# define and defined for disallow direct access

Tags: php

I have two page: rooms.php and reservation.php
User can only access to reservation.php via rooms.php
I have used `define('NOT',1);` and `if (!defined('NOT')) exit('no direct!');`
But when user goes from rooms.php to reservation.php there is error message?
Why define function not working? Thanks in advance

Comment: This doesn't make any sense what so ever. Please post the actual code you are using (not some pseudo, I assume, code) and try to be more clear in your writing.

Comment: *there is error message* Do you think it would be helpful for us to know the error message? I think so!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are calling `rooms.php` first and go to `reservation.php` via a link:

The constant will be lost after you access the other page. You should store the value in a [**session**](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php):

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['NOT'] = 1;
```

A PHP file a script that gets executed every time you call it. But that also means that all variables, constants are **lost** after the script was executed. But sessions are for preserving data through multiple page calls.

Comment: The square brackets are broken Markdown links. I think this is what he means.

Answer (score 2):

You may have a misunderstanding here: This method works only when `rooms.php` **includes** `reservation.php` using include() or require(). It does not work for, say, referers.

Is that what you are doing? In that case, your code looks correct. `rooms.php` needs to contain

```
define('NOT', 1);
```

**before** the line where `reservation.php` is included; but that should work.

Answer (score 0):

in your rooms.php add the following code before the inclusion of reservation.php

```
define('FROM_ROOM',true);
```

Within Reservation.php at the very top add

```
if(!defined('FROM_ROOM')){ exit("Please go away");}
```

So it looks like this

rooms.php:
    define('FROM_ROOM',true);
    include 'reservation.php';

reservation.php:

```
if(!defined('FROM_ROOM')){ exit("Please go away");}
echo "Im reservation.php, i only can be include by rooms.php";
```

Comment: Im not include reservation.php, Im going from rooms to reservation

Comment: Then you need to use Sessions, DEFINE is used to secure files from being directly accessed, not to allow certain html depending on the referer.

Comment: Yes you are right, As pekka said, have a misunderstanding about this issue. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need constants you need session variables or to check the HTTP referrer; constants will only work if you are *including* reservation.php and you're not, you're simply stipulating that the user should have seen rooms.php before seeing reservation.php